# Unknown Provider when testing a modal dialog

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Preface : I'm quite new to Angular and very new to unit-testing.  Be gentle.

I'm trying to run unit tests on a controller for a bootstrap modal window.

When initiating the modal I am passing through an object called `thisVersion` like so :

```
 function showShareDialog(thisVersion){
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'app/shares/views/shares-dialogue.tpl.html',
            controller: 'SharesCtrl',
            resolve:{
                thisVersion:function(){
                    return thisVersion;
                }
            }
        });
        modalInstance.result.then(function (validated) {
            // .. more code
        });
    }
```

As soon as the `Shares Controller` is instantiated I am calling a method on `thisVersion`

```
thisVersion.getList('shares').then(function(result){
    $scope.shares = result;
});
```

`thisVersion` is being passed in to the controller as a dependency, and that all works as expected.

The issue, however, is that I can't seem to inject it into my test suites.  I keep getting this error

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: thisVersionProvider <- thisVersion

This is (most of) my test suite :

```
var scope, controller, thisVersion;

  beforeEach(module('app'));
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope, _thisVersion_) {

        scope = $rootScope.$new();       
        controller = $controller('SharesCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
        thisVersion = _thisVersion_;

    }));

 it('should get a list of all shares',  function(){
     expect(thisVersion.getList).not.toBe('undefined');
 });
```

I know I am going to have to mock the call to the Api from `thisVersion.getList()` but for now I'm just concerned with getting the test suite to recognise `thisVersion`

Comment: Is thisVersion an Angular service?  You just mention its an object.